# Identity Server Login Failure

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm experiencing a server login failure with SAML WSO2 identity version 5.10 on Windows.

The issue seems to be related to the `WSO2 IdP` server. After some in-depth debugging, it looks like the server is not sending the required attributes when authenticating a user resulting in server login failure.

I've attached screenshots indicating the returned error messages as well as the relevant screens that are being affected:

[image: Register New Service Provider]

[image: Claim Configuration]

[image: SAML tracer]

I've also attemped connecting the `SAML(Erwin Mart)` and `WSO2` identity server but it didn't work.